# How do enable access to Google Analytics API for an Installed Application?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am writing a small program to retrieve and display Google Analytics information. I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error because of insufficient permissions.

I read on other posts that you have to add the email address associated with the client id you are using to access analytics in User Management.

The client id I am using however is associated with an installed application and doesn't have an email address, it only lists a client id, client secret, and redirect Urls as credentials in the developer's console.

How can I allow access for this client id when there is no associated email address listed in the developer's console to grant permissions to on the User Management page in Google Analytics?

Comment: Are you trying to let someone view your analytics data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply follow Google's [OAuth 2.0 guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) for installed applications.

1. Create a URL for authorization like you would for a web app. Only set `redirect_uri` to `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`.
2. Point your user to this URL and let him authorize your app. Then the user will receive a code.
3. Prompt the user to enter this code in your app and use it to retrieve a refresh token from Google.
4. Store the refresh token and use it to get a fresh access token whenever you need one.

Comment: If you read my question, my problem is not using OAuth. I can successfully retrieve the token and contact the API however it is not giving the client permission to access it presumably because I cannot enable permission in the User Management page in Analytics because there is no email address to give access to.

Comment: I read your question but you didn't mention that you're using OAuth and can retrieve the access token. Nor did you post details about the error message which Google normally provides in the content of the HTTP response. Without more information, all I can say is that the process I described above works for installed applications.

Comment: I am pretty sure Google uses OAuth for remote access to all of its APIs, however I did not mention this because this is not what is causing me issue.

I did provide the error:

I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error because of insufficient permissions.

Other posts mention that this is because you have to specifically give permission in Google Analytics to the client accessing the API, however installed applications do not have an email address associated with the client id so I am not sure how to do this for an installed application

The last line of my post contains my specific question.

Comment: You authorize an installed app by requesting a client ID and a client secret in the Google API Console. There's no need for an email address.